# opengl display on windows gdi (using cygwin)

Tags: opengl

So I'm having this compile error on windows:
freeglut (./testing): failed to open display ''

I did some search up and found out I need to set up the DISPLAY environment on command line by: declare -x DISPLAY=":0.0"

and further I found that on ubuntu the X server needs to be run first by: /usr/X11R6/bin/startxwin.sh

but this does not work on windows. some of the websites suggest to use a native windows gdi but they don't specify how.

Answer (score 0):

> I did some search up and found out I need to set up the DISPLAY environment on command line by: declare -x DISPLAY=":0.0"

Well, this is because you compiled your program with a library that expects a X11 server to connect to. Cygwin is a *nix runtime environment for Windows and *nix programs use X11 for their graphical output.

> some of the websites suggest to use a native windows gdi but they don't specify how.

By downloading or building yourself a version of FreeGLUT that doesn't use X11. This can be done using Cygwin, but you'll have to configure the build process to explicitly not use X11 (`./configure --with-x=no`).

The better solution would be to not use Cygwin, but instead MinGW as compiler, which is recommended anyway, since it relieves you from the Cygwin dependency.

Comment: Or is there any other method to directly compile on the windows system? (without using cygwin or mingw)

Comment: @kmes40505: Well you need a compiler. Cygwin in a *nix environment that also ships a compiler. MinGW is the GNU Compiler Collection for Windows. You could also use the MSVC compiler (available for free with the Platform SDK https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138 )